# PHP curl REST API returning no response

Tags: php, curl

I have hosted REST API, that REST API can show result if opened in web browser. But if I use curlrequest in PHP to call this REST API, the response of REST API is blank / nothing. This is my curlrequest code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myundian.rf.gd/public/user/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

Why does my curlrequest return blank response to call this REST API, but that REST API can show result if I open in web browser?

Comment: The error message that we get here is: `This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support`

Answer (score 1):

The javascript in your site was disabled. can you enable it, and let see what the response?

i try this:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://myundian.rf.gd/public/user/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

And the response is: '**This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support**'

[image]